# Removing words and symbols from columns which do not match specific criteria

Tags: python, pandas, nltk

I would need to remove from rows words which are not in English and specific symbols, like | or -, and three dots (...) if they are at the end of each row.
In order to do this, I was considering to use googletranslate or langdetect packages in Python for detecting and removing from text words not in English, and create a list for symbols.

To apply them, I was doing as follows:

```
df['Text'] == df['Text'].apply(lambda x: detect(x) == 'en') # but this just detect the rows. I would like to remove only not English words within rows, not the whole rows. 
df['Text'] = df['Text'].map(lambda x: str(x)[:-4]) # I would need to consider however a logical condition: if the last three characters are ..., then remove these three dots from the string.

to_remove=['|','-', '(',')']
df['Text'] = df['Text'].str.contains(|, to_remove) 

english_data = [word for word in df['Text'].tolist() if detect_language(word) == 'English']
```

The column I should apply these changes is

```
Text
The is in with a... - KIDS ...
BoneMA – Synthesis and Characterization of a Methacrylated ...
新型冠状病毒肺炎诊疗方案 (试行第七版) - Law Translate
```

Expected output:

```
   Text
    The is in with a... KIDS
    BoneMA Synthesis and Characterization of a Methacrylated
    Law Translate
```

Any help and suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

like regex

```
df['Text'].str.replace('[^0-9a-zA-Z.]|[.]+$',' ').str.replace('\s{2,}',' ')
```

Output

```
0                 The is in with a... KIDS 
1    BoneMA Synthesis and Characteriof a M 
2                             Law Translate
```

Comment: in case I wanted to include also the condition words with length greater than 3, how could I include this in your formula?

Comment: exclude words having len > 3 -- \w{4,} should work

Comment: something like thiis: `df['Text'].str.replace('[^0-9a-zA-Z.]|[.]+$',' ').str.replace('\s{2,}',' ').str.replace('len > 3 -- \w{4,}',' ')`?

Comment: you can simply add in the first replace condition...-> replace('[^0-9a-zA-Z.]|[.]+$| +|\w{4,}',' ')